# How should the GetService method in IDependencyResolver implementation for Unity look like?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'd like to use Unity as an IoC container for an ASP.NET MVC 3 app but am having trouble with my `UnityDependecyResolver` class. It currently looks like this (copied from somewhere on the web as I don't think Unity itself comes with this):

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this._container = container;
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get this runtime error when trying to visit any controller:

> The IControllerFactory 'System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Account'.

[This StructureMap article](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/1/20/structuremap-and-asp-net-mvc-3-getting-started) suggests that I should amend the `GetService` method, however, I'm quite new to both MVC and Unity and I'm not sure how exactly should it look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Unity.MVC project](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation and for me it works

```
   public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver 
    {

        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

        public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(serviceType))
            {
                return _container.CreateChildContainer().Resolve(serviceType);
            }

            if (_container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
            {
                return _container.CreateChildContainer().Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.CreateChildContainer().ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }

    }
```